# Titles in tablayout aren't visible

Tags: java, android

Working with `TabLayout` Problem is Titles aren't visible i overide `getPageTitle` in adapter also i returned a string which would be title but that string doesn't show up. I have debugged the app i am getting titles from server.

And yes i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675884/tablayout-title-arent-visible-in-android) but it wasn't working too.

Here is relevant java code and xml files.

```
 private void loadCategories() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Constants.URL_GET_CATEGORIES, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                categoriesDTO = Constants.gson.fromJson(response,CategoriesDTO.class);
                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                setTabLayout();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        ApplicationController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }



    private void setTabLayout(){
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

Adapter for the viewpager.

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new ContentFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoriesDTO.getCategories().size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title =categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getTitle();
        return title;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/home_drawer_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

This is the output

[image]

Here is gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.softoven.ultron"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.6.1'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
```

}

How to make it work?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made following changes in tablayout xml then titles were visible

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#fff"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            >
```

Comment: Thanks! tabMode="scrollable" made my tab titles appear. I did everything else like in the books (adapter with getPageTitle() etc.).

Answer (score 4):

In my case I solved this by replacing,

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

By,

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(
                        tabLayout));
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
});
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: totally.. i had this same problem.. title not showing.. and this solution worked for me.

Comment: have you tried giving `app:tabSelectedTextColor"` to `TabLayout`?

Comment: no i didn't give this attribute, don't they have default color for titles?

Comment: try that.. maybe your titles are taking primary color.. so they are not visible

Comment: let me check the. i don't think it will work cus selected tab title wasn't eveing covering the space

Comment: It's working for me.. make sure you have set viewpager Adapter before setting `addOnPageChangeListener`

Comment: removing tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); was the trick for me. Why?¿

Comment: @Terranology in order to use `setupWithViewPager` you must override `getPageTitle` in your FragmentAdapter

Answer (score 1):

> This will do Trick for you. Add your `Tab Layout` in Runnable.

```
tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Can you show me your `Gradle` ? please post it in above Question.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir I think it may be bug in design `com.android.support:design:23.3.0` . have you tried using downgrade version for this like `com.android.support:design:22.2.0` this works currently for me.

Comment: now titles are showing but scroll isn't smooth i have to scroll twice to switch to new tab

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir For that their is something wrong with `View Pager` itself try to crosscheck that. and appreciate my answer if it's helpful to you thanks :) I will edit my answer for downgrade version..

Comment: actually your answer wasn't the solution. I am working with latest support design library and i need to make some changes in xml in order make this work but now problem is with scroll. i appreciate that you put some efforts to help me out.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Yes i know it is not but i am looking into scroll isn't smooth. and for design support only you can use downgrade version because i have read somewhere it's defined as bug what you have in your OP. so i have to give that solution.

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir For view pager smooth scroll try by adding this `myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`.

Comment: doesn't work either. If i downgrade the lib then i get lots of error sine my target sdk is 23

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Let me know brother for my knowledge if you get any other alternate solution for this. i have tried with what all i know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112045/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-zeeshan-shabbir).

Answer (score -1):

In your styles:

```
 <style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>
```

In your XML:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dip"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff" />
```